# magento pagination not showing

Tags: magento, pagination

I was trying to search all over the internet but no luck.

I included in my page

```
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
```

I found that in the getPagerHtml this code is returning false

```
$this->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager')
```

then after going to getChild, I found out that

```
$this->_children[$name]
```

is not set. $this->_children array size is 0 which is the main reason why getPagerHtml always returns false.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: where you are trying to fix pagination?

Comment: I had these included in the list.phtml `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>` the `<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>` was found on the toolbar.phtml. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11528/pagination-on-products-page